# How do i use Math.sin() in javascript to get correct answer?

Tags: javascript, math

When I use Math.sin(90) for calculating Sine of 90 degrees in javascript it returns 0.8939966636005565, but sin(90) is 1. Is there a way to fix that? I need accurate values for any angle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo">Click the button calculate value of 90 degrees.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Math.sin(90);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The trig functions in JavaScript operate on radians, not degrees.

Comment: @Pointy Possible duplicate, i didn't know it works in radians.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Math.sin` expects the input to be in radian, but you are expecting the result of 90 degree. Convert it to radian, like this

```
console.log(Math.sin(90 * Math.PI / 180.0));
# 1
```

As per the wikipedia's [Radian to Degree conversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees),

```
Angle in Radian = Angle in Degree * Math.PI / 180
```

Comment: How come `console.log(Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / 180));` returns `1.2246467991473532e-16` instead of `0`?

Comment: @nils - Notice that the number `1.2246467991473532e-16` is very very small, and It is equivalent to `0.00000000000000012246467991473532` (notice the `e-16`) at the end of the number, which is a scientific form of writing a number.

Answer (score 6):

The sin function in Javascript takes radians, not degrees. You need to convert 90 to radians to get the correct answer:

```
Math.sin(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
```